# Iterating multiple arrays in shell

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a set of arrays which are created upon certain ending patterns. I want to add some computed values to it by iterating it one by one.
So far I have tried doing this,

```
#!/bin/bash
patternBA=()
patternCA=()
patternDA=()

types=(BA CA DA)

for iterator in "${types[@]}"
do
#I need to use this individual iterator for 
#computational purpose to gain the "anyIntegerValue"
pattern'$iterator'+=(anyIntegerValue)
done
```

Expected array contents:

```
patternBA=(anyIntegerValue)
patternCA=(anyIntegerValue)
patternDA=(anyIntegerValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is better achieved with associative arrays:

```
$ declare -A pattern
$ for((i=0;i<${#types[@]};i++));do pattern[${types[$i]}]=$i; done
$ echo ${pattern["BA"]}
0
$ echo ${pattern["CA"]}
1
$ echo ${pattern["DA"]}
2
```

Comment: Defined arrays are empty, there are supposed to be populated one by one while considering those unique patterns corresponding to its array. This will not work out for current scenario. Thank you for your time bro

Comment: @DazzlerJay Sorry, missunderstood the question. I'm editing it right now.

Comment: Works well when I add single value per key, but when I add a loop to add multiple values per key then it retrieves only last value . Appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: @DazzlerJay  If you want multiple values, look into https://stackoverflow.com/q/6149679/3701431  Alternatively, consider just using different language altogether like Python, where you can have key-value pairs (dictionaries), with value being any type, even a list like [1,2,3]

Comment: @DazzlerJay, bash does not have multidimensional arrays. I also recommend you us a different tool.